# Graphing Fourier triangle wave

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So far, no success trying to recreate this in Latex:

[image]

The code I'm using is this:

```
 \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{ifthen}

 \begin{document}

 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5]
 \begin{axis}[
 width=\textwidth,
 xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
 ymin = 0, ymax = 3,
 domain = -1: 1,
 xlabel = $x$,
 ylabel = $y$,
 axis x line = center, 
every axis x label/.append style = {below},
every axis y label/.append style = {left},
samples = 100,
xtick = {-1, 0, 1},
xticklabels = {$-1$, $0$, $1$},
declare function = {
  s(\x) = ifthenelse(\x < pi, 1, 0);
  s0(\x) = 0.5  + (2 / (pi * pi)) * (1-cos(pi)) * cos(deg(\x * pi));
  s1(\x) = s0(\x) + (2 / (pi * pi * 9)) * (1-cos((\x * pi * 3)) * cos(deg(\x * pi * 3));
  s2(\x) = s1(\x) + (2 / (pi * pi * 25)) * (1-cos((\x * pi * 5)) * cos(deg(\x * pi * 5));
  s3(\x) = s1(\x) + (2 / (pi * pi * 49)) * (1-cos((\x * pi * 7)) * cos(deg(\x * pi * 7));
}, ]
\addplot[ultra thick, black] {s(x)};
\addplot[thick, blue] {s0(x)};
\addplot[thick, red] {s1(x)};
\addplot[thick, orange] {s2(x)};
\addplot[thick, cyan] {s3(x)};
\legend{signal, $s_0$, $s_1$, $s_2$, $s_3$};    
% labels
\draw[gray, dashed] (-1, 0) -- (-1, 2);
\draw[gray, dashed] (1, 0) -- (1, 2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

And the current output is:

[image]
Probably my error is more of mathematical nature than Latex related, but if someone could help me I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: You're a bit inconsistent with regard to the arguments to the trigonometric functions, which assumes degrees as input. In some cases you do convert the argument to degrees, in other cases not. You can actually tell `pgfplots` to use radians for the trig functions, so you could remove `deg` everywhere you have that, and then add `trig format=rad` to the `axis` options. Either that, or add in `deg()` where you've left it out.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems here, one related to `pgfplots`, one related to the mathematics. As I mentioned in my comment, you are a bit inconsistent when it comes to the arguments to the cosine function. `pgf` assumes that the input comes in degrees, so when you input radians you should convert it to degrees. You do this in some cases, but not all.

You can also tell `pgfplots` to assume radians for trig functions, by adding `trig format plots=rad` to the `axis` options. (`trig format plots` is better than `trig formats` which I mentioned in my comment, as the latter will also influence rotation of things like the ylabel.)

The mathematical problem is that in `s1`, `s2` and `s3` you have `(1-cos((\x * pi * m))`, which should be `(1-cos(pi * m))`, i.e. no `\x*` and the parenthesis are wrong as well.

In the code below there are a few other changes as well, to make it a bit closer to your sketch. I also defined a function

```
sN(\N, \x) = (2 / (pi * pi * \N * \N)) * (1-cos(pi * \N)) * cos(\x * pi * \N);
```

to reduce code duplication and make the other function definitions easier.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 width=\textwidth,height=0.5\textwidth,
 xmin = -1, xmax = 1,
 ymin = 0, ymax = 1.2, % changed from 3
 domain = -1: 1,
 xlabel = $x$,
 ylabel = $y$,
 hide y axis, % from your sketch you don't seem to want any y-axis
 axis x line = bottom, % changed from center
 samples = 101,
 xtick = {-1, 0, 1},
 trig format plots=rad, % added this, so pgfplots assumes radians for trig functions
 clip=false, % to avoid clipping half of the dashed lines
 declare function = {
   % signal function
   s = ifthenelse(\x<0, \x+1, -\x+1);
   % constant term
   s0 = 1/2;
   % generic function for term number N in the series
   sN(\N, \x) = (2 / (pi * pi * \N * \N)) * (1-cos(pi * \N)) * cos(\x * pi * \N);
   s1(\x) = s0  + sN(1,\x);
   s2(\x) = s1(\x) + sN(3,\x);
   s3(\x) = s2(\x) + sN(5,\x);
   s4(\x) = s3(\x) + sN(7,\x);
 }
]

\addplot[ultra thick, black, samples at={-1,0,1}] {s};
\addplot[thick, black] {s0};
\addplot[thick, blue] {s1(x)};
\addplot[thick, red] {s2(x)};
\addplot[thick, orange] {s3(x)};
\addplot[thick, cyan] {s4(x)};
\legend{signal, $s_0$, $s_1$, $s_2$, $s_3$, $s_4$};

% just a different method for making the vertical dashed lines
% yours works fine as well
\addplot [forget plot, ycomb, dashed, gray] coordinates {(-1,1.2)(1,1.2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```